# Does createElement() trigger a reflow before the element is appended to the DOM? Confusing abt DocumentFragment behavior

Tags: javascript, html, dom, optimization, reflow

I'm trying to figure out when exactly a reflow or repaint is triggered when an element is created.

The context for this is trying to understand if a DocumentFragment is necessary if the elements are not appended to extant items in the DOM tree until the end of the function. Here's an example:

##### HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id=target> </div>
</body>
```

##### JS:

```
const ul = document.CreateElement("ul")

for (let i=0; i<100000; i++) {

   let li = document.CreateElement("li")
   let li_text = document.CreateTextNode("Node #: " + i)

   li.appendChild(li_text)
   ul.appendChild(li)

}

document.getElementById("target").appendChild(ul)
```

In this example, is a reflow triggered every time an <li> is created in the loop? Or is only one reflow triggered after the <ul> is appended to <div id=target>?

If it's the former, would the appropriate way to prevent this multiple-reflowing be: (1) creating a document fragment, (2) appending a <ul> child to the fragment, (3) getting that <ul> and appending the <li> to it, then (4) appending the fragment to the <div>?

If it's the later... then what's the advantage of using a document fragment in contexts like this?

#### Context

I'm working on project which involves dynamically creating many lists -- I'm working on performance optimization, and am unsure how to monitor or test for this kind of behavior. Typically I test on Firefox, with apache hosting from a local directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does createElement() trigger a reflow before the element is appended to the DOM?

No. If the element isn't in the DOM, there's no (re)flow to calculate. [(Re)flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Reflow) relates to elements in the page being displayed.

> If it's the later... then what's the advantage of using a document fragment in contexts like this?

In that specific case where you're only adding one top-level element, a fragment doesn't help. But if you wanted to build a structure with several elements at the top level, using a fragment lets you do that and then append them to the active DOM all at once rather than one at a time.

For example, let's say hypothetically you already had that `ul` in the document and you wanted to append those 100,000 `li` elements to it. You could use a fragment so you only modify the active DOM once rather than 100,000 times:

```js
const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (let i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
    // Note: There's no need to call createTextNode explicitly here
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = `Node #: ${i}`;
    frag.appendChild(li);
}

document.getElementById("target-ul").appendChild(frag);
```

```html
<ul id="target-ul"></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear! This behavior is what I had guessed but couldn't find any specifics on.